# How to convert Large XML data into Excel or CSV

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have am XML of 100MB approx 2Million records. I have looked for every option on the internet but I cant find any solution.

All I require is to convert the XML data into Excel and if the data is large then it should move to another sheet.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can directly import your xml into excel if you have a schema.
Even without a schema, excel will open the file, generating a schema of its own.
Also, 100 MB isn't large for excel. So, it should be able to handle it.

Comment: Thanks Praveen S, I tried using that option but its giving me an error something like "either no data or only some data would be copied" so I was hoping if you can guide me how to convert the file into CSV or if I can have a loop which can add sheets automatically to my dataset rather than giving an error.

Comment: How does your XML file look like? If it is not properly formatted, then you can use python(or any other programming language with an XML library) and generate csv yourself. Check this link: http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/